# If a user signs in through a different provider with the same UID, will the realm of that user be changed?

Tags: palantir-foundry, palantir-foundry-security

We had an issue where we needed to delete the old realm's provider and collector before the user correctly got assigned the new realm when signing in through the new provider.

Answer (score 0):

If a user logs in through a different provider, Multipass will create an entirely new user (because the new user is in a different realm than the existing user). Users are matched by (realm, providerId) pairs.

Comment: What would be a good way to have 2 identity providers simultaneously, mapping to the same user? Or is that not currently supported?

Comment: The above is not supported ^